# Autofilter less than or equal to won't work

Tags: excel, vba

Why doesn't this work? I only gives me the rows with the date 2020-06-08.

```
Today = "2020-06-09"
Yesterday = "2020-06-08"

sheets("eBS").Rows("8:" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=TCN, Criteria1:=">=" & Yesterday , _
Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Today
```

To get the rows with the date 2020-06-09 I have to use:

```
Today = "2020-06-09"
Yesterday = "2020-06-08"

sheets("eBS").Rows("8:" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=TCN, Criteria1:=">=" & Yesterday , _
Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Today + 1
```

Am I missing some logic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current logic will not work if your datetimes include a time portion.

`"<=" & Today` will not include any date/times falling on today's date, but after 12:00 AM.

The easiest way to include them is to check if they are *less than* tomorrow (but not less than or equal to).

Comment: Sometimes Today might be 2020-06-09 and Yesterday 2020-06-06. Like today is a Monday and Yesterday is a Friday, but there might be dates on Saturday and Sunday if people work on those days. So all the dates between Today and Yesterday.

Comment: But doesn't ```">=``` mean less than or equal to?

Comment: Well then your variable names are misleading... you might consider something different. But I can't reproduce the problem. My sample code included `Criteria1:=">=" & Date - 1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Date` and it returned rows for both today and yesterday.

Comment: That is weird! I also tried ```sheets("eBS").Rows("8:" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=TCN, Criteria1:=">=" & "2020-06-08" ,
Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & "2020-06-09"``` with the same result...

Comment: I know what's happening. You have a time portion in the date. `<= & Today` won't work if there's a time portion greater than 12:00AM.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually simplified the code since I didn't thought it was necessary to use it all, but it actually says ```Today = Left(Inf.Range("N10").Value, 10)``` I thought I would only get the date part then.

Comment: Do note that you want *less than* tomorrow, not *less than or equal to.*

Comment: If I view the variable Today in the Watch window, or whatever it's called in English, it's equal to 2020-06-09. But is there always a time portion there, hidden?

Comment: What I meant above was that I simplified the code in the question, not in the excel file!

Comment: It is the Watch window in English. `Today` is a `String`... so just text. But date/times in the sheet are just formatted numbers. The integer part of the number is the day, and the decimal part is the time. So if you say `<=Today`, the number that corresponds to `Today` has no decimals, and thus you're saying `<= Today 12:00 AM`.

Comment: It's actually a date in the Watch Window. Ok, so is Left(,10) not needed then? Or does it turn time to a standard time like 12:00 AM like you said? I use it to compare only the date part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217752/discussion-between-bigben-and-jens).